# Why does query document erroneously match field in array of subdocuments using value `null`?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to [match a field without specifying an array index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#match-a-field-without-specifying-array-index) with the following query:

```
db.games.find( { 'players.userId': userId } )
```

where `userId` is either a String or is `null` if no user is logged in. I expect the `count()` of the above cursor to be `0` when `userId === null`, but I find that this is not the case -- all documents for which `players` is an empty array `[]` are counted. I would expect that `players.userId` would be `undefined` perhaps, but not `null`. What is going on here? Does mongo use `==` and not `===`, coercing `undefined` and `null` to be the same value?

Comment: Apparently, you have documents with that field set to `null`.

Comment: when count() returns unexpected number, leave off the count() and see what find returns - those are the documents you didn't expect.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not necessarily. See the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain consider the following documents:

```
{ 
    name: "PacMan",
    players: [ { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: "Ted" }, { userId: "Death" } ]
}
{ 
    name: "Frogger", 
    players: [ { userId: null }, { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: null } ] 
}
{
    name: "Defender",
    players: [ ]
}
```

If you issue a query like:

```
>db.games.find({ "players.userId" : "Bill" })

{ 
    name: "PacMan",
    players: [ { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: "Ted" }, { userId: "Death" } ]
}
{ 
    name: "Frogger", 
    players: [ { userId: null }, { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: null } ] 
}
```

You will get the two documents you expect that has the player with that userId present in the array. But if we change that to `null`

```
>db.games.find({ "players.userId" : null })

{ 
    name: "Frogger", 
    players: [ { userId: null }, { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: null } ] 
}
{
    name: "Defender",
    players: [ ]
}
```

Wait a minute, you get a document you didn't expect. There are no elements in the players array. So why is it matching? Let's look at this form:

```
>db.games.find({ "players.userId" : {$exists: true } })
{ 
    name: "PacMan",
    players: [ { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: "Ted" }, { userId: "Death" } ]
}
{ 
    name: "Frogger", 
    players: [ { userId: null }, { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: null } ] 
}
```

Now that gives us results **only** where the `players.userId` field is *actually* there, and the third document will not be included as it has no items that match this condition. So finally consider the last form:

```
>db.games.find({ $and: [
    {"players.userId" : {$exists: true }}, 
    {"players.userId": null }
] })

{ 
    name: "Frogger", 
    players: [ { userId: null }, { userId: "Bill" }, { userId: null } ] 
}
```

This will find the result whsere there is a field present and it has a `null` value.

So to sum up. Even if an array does not contain any elements that would match a `null` value test it may still return as a result as the `null` condition is considered to be true as the empty items evaluates to `null`. If you want to **exclude** this case then you use [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in order to test for the presence of the field in the first place.

Comment: Thank. However, it's confusing to me that the query would match on empty arrays because these arrays do not contain elements on which to match.

Comment: @DonnyWinston Re-read the answer. Search the documentation given the clauses I used. It's not confusing, there is a **really** good reason why this is so. It's best you understand that for your own development.