# Filtter by array data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, filter

I have a **mongodb** data base like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "data" : "object 1",
    "my_array" : [
        {"arraydata" : "1"},
        {"arraydata" : "2"}
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "data" : "object 2",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("530d24150fef5d9b065909ca"),
    "data" : "object 3",
    "my_array" : [{"arraydata" : "1"}]
}
```

I want to make a query which **only returns** document that contains some data in **my_array**, in this case it'd returned the first and the last one.

I understood that `$where` statement is slow, so I want to get a better approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does query document erroneously match field in array of subdocuments using value \`null\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21995367/why-does-query-document-erroneously-match-field-in-array-of-subdocuments-using-v)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the array never exists but is empty, as in your example data, then the following is simpler:

db.c.find({my_array: {$exists: true}})

However, if you want to filter out documents where the array exists but is empty, they your answer is good.

Comment: I think this answer is better than mine, so I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got it using:

```
db.document.find({'my_array.0': {$exists: true}})
```

Is there a better approach?